# require file on the top level directory

Tags: ruby, require

Here is my project structure:

```
/app
--/lib
----/porter.rb
--/spec
----/porter_spec.rb
```

In file porter_spec.rb i have include directive:

```
require '../lib/porter'
```

Now I'm trying to run the test:

```
cd app
rspec
```

and get the error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ../lib/porter (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Dropbox/development/myprojects/lj-parser/spec/porter_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

How can I require file on lib folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, your current dir is not what you think it is.

You should use [`require_relative`](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html) (ruby 1.9+):

```
require_relative '../lib/porter'
```

Answer (score 3):

In ruby1.9, you can use:

```
require_relative '../lib/porter'
```

In ruby1.8 or higher, you can use:

```
require File.expand_path("../lib/porter", __FILE__)
```